# CircleCi and CodeCov: The '<' operator is reserved for future use

Tags: bash, unit-testing, curl, circleci, codecov

I am trying to integrate `CodeCov` in `CircleCI`, but the command

`bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)`

returns

`The '<' operator is reserved for future use.` when executed in the pipeline.

I am following the documentation that I found for

- CodeCov: https://docs.codecov.io/v4.3.0/docs/about-the-codecov-bash-uploader
- CircleCI: https://circleci.com/docs/reference-2-1/#jobs

My `config.yml` has the following steps:

```
steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: "Run Unit Tests"
          command: dotnet.exe test ./UnitTests --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
      - run:
          name: Upload CodeCov.io Data
          command: bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
          when: always # Uploads code coverage results, pass or fail
```

I have also tried with just `curl -s https://codecov.io/bash` but in this way I get the error
`Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Uri.`

Has anyone of you made this integration?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I had to add the .exe to the curl command:

```
- run:
    name: Upload Coverage Results
    command: curl.exe -s https://codecov.io/bash | bash -s --
    when: "always"
```

Now it builds but can't find the report.

```
==> Circle CI detected. 
    project root: C:/Users/circleci/project 
    Yaml not found, that's ok! Learn more at http://docs.codecov.io/docs/codecov-yaml 
==> Running gcov in C:/Users/circleci/project (disable via -X gcov) 
FIND: Parameter format not correct
 
==> Python coveragepy not found 
==> Searching for coverage reports in: 
    + C:/Users/circleci/project 
--> No coverage report found. 
    Please visit http://docs.codecov.io/docs/supported-languages 
CircleCI received exit code 0
```

Comment: you can specify a path to the report you want to upload with `-f` flag: `-f "app/path/to/coverage/file.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

> *“The '<' operator is reserved for future use.”*

Try to run your command as shown below:

```
cmd /c "<your command>"
```